# Assets, participants and Transactions in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am working on how to develop a blockchain app using Hyperledger Composer. Since I have just begun with Hyperledger Fabric so I am pretty confused over Some Points-:
1) What are assets, participants and transactions.
2) What is the meaning of the symbol '-->' used for some variable.
3) Why do we need .bna file.

I am new to this concept so please bear with me as I have tried with documentation but it confuses me even more.

Comment: This might be helpful - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-blockchain-network-using-hyperledger-fabric-and-composer-e06644ff801d
P.S. - I wrote that tutorial

Answer (score 1):

An `asset` is anything of value, whether physical or virtual.

A `participant` is a person or organization participating (taking part) in the blockchain network.

A `transaction` is an operation submitted by a participant to modify the blockchain. It could be transferring or modifying the amount of an asset. It could be recording an event. In any case, it modifies or creates a value in the blockchain network's `ledger` (also known as `world state`).